# X-box 360 Slim, bad picture quality

Tags: xbox-360

Is there any way to improve the picture quality while LCD monitor is used as display.

I am using DELL LCD 19" widescreen monitor.

I am using xbox composite cable to hook up monitor and xbox.

**Updated Question**

Though the solution was to use DVI-HDMI converter, the problem will be still there with audio.

So, will this thing work for me ? This is a VGA HDMI converter with 3.5mm audio.

Is the same kind available with DVI ?

Since this converter has VGA, will I get good quality ?

[image][image][image]

Comment: You want to use a purely digital signal chain, which means cutting out the tuner card and the analog connector.  If your monitor has HDMI in, that would be ideal.  Otherwise, you'll have to use an HDMI to DVI converter and an HDMI audio extractor, but in the end, this still might not fully work.

Comment: VGA is still analog, but at least it's not as bad as composite or component cables.  This would still be a better solution.

Answer (score 8):

The highest resolution with an rca connector is either NTSC 480i (720x480) or PAL 576i (720x576).

The best thing you can do would be to hook it up directly to the monitor using either a HDMI or DVI cable. Both can get you 1080p (1920×1080) resolution.

If your monitor doesn't have HDMI but DVI, you can either get a [HDMI-DVI cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001TH7T2U) or if you already have a HDMI cable lying around, you can use a [HDMI-DVI adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0035B4LJM). Both will work with your xbox 360.

Comment: I don't have HDMI port on my monitor... and how to connect DVI cable to xbox directly ?

Comment: @hsuk I'll ad it to the answer.

Comment: I think this is my solution ... 

http://www.optimization-world.com/img/prod/hdmi_female_to_dvi_male_large.jpg

Comment: You'll probably still need an [HDMI audio extractor](http://www.amazon.com/Panlong-Extractor-Splitter-Repeater-Converter/dp/B00HF2YJ08/ref=sr_1_49?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1387464333&sr=1-49&keywords=hdmi+audio+extractor) in order to have game audio.

Comment: yeah, I realized that... is there any alternative for audio extractor ?

Comment: @hsuk not likely, you can't split the video through HDMI and audio through the component cables on the 360 IIRC.

Comment: yeah, I am doomed, either I have play low quality mode or I should buy LED...

Comment: check updated question please...